# How to update a column value in a row for specific value in another column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 3 columns `id`, `type`, `type_value`.

They're already populated with values. `type` column contains repeating values `type1`, `type2`, `type3`, `type4`.

`type_value` contains a Counter object which has frequencies of occurrences in it.

All I need is to perform some operations on the Counter dictionary and update the `type_value` column when the `type` is matched with **`type1`** and leave the other rows untouched.

**Input:**

```
id  type    type_value
1   type1   Counter object that needs to be updated
2   type2   some random value
3   type3   some random value
4   type4   some random value
5   type1   Counter object that needs to be updated
6   type2   some random value
7   type3   some random value
8   type4   some random value
9   type1   Counter object that needs to be updated
10  type2   some random value
11  type3   some random value
12  type4   some random value
13  type1   Counter object that needs to be updated
14  type2   some random value
15  type3   some random value
16  type4   some random value
```

**Output:**

```
id  type    type_value
1   type1   Do an operation on this and update with new values
2   type2   some random value
3   type3   some random value
4   type4   some random value
5   type1   Do an operation on this and update with new values
6   type2   some random value
7   type3   some random value
8   type4   some random value
9   type1   Do an operation on this and update with new values
10  type2   some random value
11  type3   some random value
12  type4   some random value
13  type1   Do an operation on this and update with new values
14  type2   some random value
15  type3   some random value
16  type4   some random value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitler rows by condition and apply your custom function:

```
def func(x):
    #your operation
    return x

mask = df['type'] == 'type1'
df.loc[mask, 'type_value'] = df.loc[mask, 'type_value'].apply(func)
```

Comment: It is updating all the rows instead of just the rows that have `type == type1`.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf - hmmm, it is weird, because my solution filter only values with `mask`, check it by `print(df.loc[mask, 'type_value'])`. Maybe problem is something else.

Comment: The `print(df.loc[mask, 'type_value'])` is printing only the rows that are having `type1`. But in the dataframe all the 4 type's values are updated with the value of  `type1` column. Like `Counter object that needs to be updated` is copied to all the rows.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf - so need change `df.loc[mask, 'type_value'] = df.loc[mask, 'type_value'].apply(func)` to `df.loc[mask, 'type_value'] = df['type_value'].apply(func)` ?

Comment: No. the values for only the rows in mask should be updated. But it's updating every row not just the ones in mask.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf - So it depends of function, is possible add some sample function for check my solution?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. It's working. I was using other name for the same column as well and somehow it messed everything up. Now it's working as expected. Thanks a lot. :-)